# How to setup Asteriesk in WINDOWS machine and how to get started?

Tags: windows-xp, voip, asterisk

How to setup Asteriesk in WINDOWS machine and how to get started?

any tutorials would be helpful

I googled it but it didn't turn into helpful things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Start here](http://www.asteriskwin32.com/) for Asteriskwin32, although for anything more than a 'play' system I'd recommend a 'proper' Linux-based install such as [Trixbox](http://fonality.com/trixbox/) or [PBX in a flash](http://pbxinaflash.net/)

Comment: I have installed it , now how to proceed configuration, I have chkd the videos there, but there is no such component in this installation as they have shown in video

Comment: Oh, I see. I run several Asterisk installations on Linux but have not used the Windows-based version. Hopefully someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: Ok For linux i read somewhere i need to create a bootable cd for installation, my doubt is suppose I have linux [ubuntu for me] installed in a drive which doesn'thave another partition, can i install it in the same partition without harming ubuntu ?

Comment: You can if you install everything manually, but not from the automated install disks as they wipe the machine. I wouldn't recommend a manual install as your first step into Asterisk on Linux as there can be a high degree of tweaking required.

Comment: Or askozia pbx (http://www.askozia.com/) very user friendly.

Comment: @lfx is it free and OOS ?

Comment: @abc is under CC license.